# Solving coupled PDEs numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following system of PDEs for which I have given parameters $\gamma, \tau$ and $\mu$,

$$\begin{align}
T_t = &\ \gamma\,(L +\tau F-T)\\
F_t = & -F_x-(F-LT)\\
L_t = &\ \mu L_{xx}+(F-LT)\end{align}$$

with no flux boundary conditions at $x=0$ and $x=\infty$ for $F$ and $L$. The initial conditions are $L=T=F=e^{-x^2}$.

Sadly Mathematica failed to simulate as the order of the derivative in the boundary condition for $F$, $(F_x(0)=F_x(\infty)=0)$ is the same as the order of the derivative of $F$ w.r.t $x$ in the PDE.

Any alternatives to Mathematica?

Comment: There is plenty of [information and examples](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=matlab+systems+of+pdes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=8-lqVvanFYi7mQXVobPIDQ) on how to code systems of coupled PDEs on Matlab.

Comment: I do not use MATLAB. Could you please point me to something specific?